# Thunderbird Zenity dialog

Tags: thunderbird, zenity

Whenever I get a new email in Thunderbird, zinity pops up with a modal dialog box:
[image]

This is very anoying and when I'm away for some time and get back, I have to click OK/Cancel a dozen time to get rid of it. How can I disable this?

I also get the notification with subject/from etc but that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open: `Edit -> Preferences -> General -> "When new messages arrive:"`

Unchecking the `Show an alert`-Box should do the trick.

If this does not help, try to disable the extensions / addons to trace down which is causing the issue.

Comment: No, that does not help :(

Comment: Are you using any extension?

Comment: Bingo!, I removed some addons and it seems fixed. I suspect that an old Gnome add on caused it. Modify your answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome integration > Gnome integration Options > unchecking the 
Show icon in system tray (recuires Zenety)