# How to restore proper notification handling with gnome-session, Openbox, Cairo-dock?

Tags: cairo-dock, notification-area, gnome-session, zenity

I run Ubuntu 14.04 with gdm and gnome-session, but I disabled dash/metacity/unity and use Openbox and Cairo Dock. Last week, all was fine - notifications appeared in a transient dock popup. After doing software updates this week, this no longer works. If I do

```
zenity  --notification --title "alert" --text "notice me"
```

instead of the normal out-of-the-way notification, I get a dialog box that steals focus
and which is persistent (must be dismissed):

[image: the screenshot]

which is disruptive (and which will get dismissed accidentally if I'm in the middle of typing something and press the spacebar before I noticed the popup).

I have 'Notification Area' on in Cairo Dock, and also enabled 'Notification Area Old' but nothing works.

How do I restore correct notification handling?

Answer (score 0):

Zenity "notifications" don't use the standard notification system (`libnotify`). What you see is standard behaviour. If you want to send notifications you have to use `notify-send` (available in  the `libnotify-bin` package).

Comment: but zenity --notification used to work for me as described - I got nonintrusive notifications, not dialogs.  I have multiple scripts that call it.

Comment: @djb Mmh, that's strange. Zenity has always been a window for me (and I'm [not the only one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217087/thunderbird-zenity-dialog)).